# Role and position of “auch” as a focus particle

Tags: meaning, word-order

Under the chapter of focus particles (role and position), my grammar book gives two use cases for using *auch*:

> 1. refers to the whole sentence and is placed before nicht, modal, locative and verb 2 position
>
> *Ich konnte meinen Vater gestern dank deiner Hilfe **auch** pünktlich am Bahnhof abholen.*
>
> 2. Highlights a part of the sentence and is placed just before the part of the sentence highlighted
>
> *Ich schenke dir dieses Jahr **auch** Blumen zum Geburtstag (nicht nur Pralinen).*

The first use case where *auch* refers to the whole sentence confuses me as I am not sure what is the logical scope of *auch* as „*nicht nur*“ to cover the whole sentence.

My guess is - Somebody else could pick up their father yesterday punctually at the railway station, thanks to your help.  And I too could pick up my father yesterday punctually at the railway station, thanks to your help.

The reason that I am not sure of this, is that it would be then the equivalent of (in my view) :

> **Auch** ich konnte meinen Vater gestern dank deiner Hilfe pünktlich am Bahnhof abholen.

Source: (B2-C1) Grammatik aktiv, Cornelsen 2019, page 24

Comment: Das ist aber auch schwierig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note: I know these as *modal particles*, not *focus particles* -- that might help for googling.)

In the second example, *auch* serves as a modifier with the meaning *nicht nur*, as you rightly observed.  It can modify every noun phrase by immediately following it.

However, in its usage as a particle, it does not mean *nicht nur*, and has restricted positions within the sentence (mainly following the verb).  In particular, the usage in your second example is as a particle, and not as *nicht nur*.

I'll give you some examples:

- *Auch ich konnte ihn abholen*: I, too, was able to pick him up. (Not only me)
- *Auch konnte ich ihn abholen*: Additionally, I was able to pick him up. (Sentence adverb)
- *Ich konnte auch ihn abholen*: I was able to pick up him, too. (Not only someone else)
- *Ich konnte ihn auch abholen*: I was indeed able to pick him up. (Particle: "according to what was expected"; often, a "but" sentence will follow)
- *Ich konnte ihn auch **pünktlich** abholen*: I also was able to get him **on time**.  (Focus on *pünktlich* as "unexpected" information -- usually including prosodic focus, without which it is ambiguous with the "indeed" meaning)
- *Ich schenke dir auch Blumen*: This one's complicated.  It can have multiple interpretations:

  1. Additionally, I will give you flowers. (With regular prosody, sentence adverb)
  2. I will give you flowers, too.  (Prosody: *Ich schenke dir **auch Blumen***, "not only")
  3. "I will fulfill your expectation/requirements by giving you flowers, even though you might have expected the opposite" (Prosody: *Ich **schenke** dir auch **Blumen**!*; particle usage that's difficult to translate)

In the very last examply, you really have to think of someone defending themselves (*Doch, ich denke an deinen Geburtstag! Ich schenke dir auch Blumen!*) or reinforcing a point (*Ich schenke ihm auch immer Blumen. Aber es hilft nichts!*).

Answer (score 2):

If an **auch** at the beginng of a sentence refers to the whole sentence, it must occupy position 1 and the verb must follow:

> Auch konnte ich meinen Vater gestern dank deiner Hilfe pünktlich am Bahnhof abholen.

Whereas in the case of

> Auch ich konnte meinen Vater gestern dank deiner Hilfe pünktlich am Bahnhof abholen.

the **auch** refers to **Ich**: "I too could..."

Answer (score 2):

The first one can be changed into small scope like this:

> Ich konnte meinen Vater gestern **rechtzeitig am Flughafen** und dank
>   deiner Hilfe **auch** *pünktlich am Bahnhof* abholen.

now the "abholen" also counts for "Flughafen". The "auch" only rules "pünktlich am Bahnhof".

---

The second can be made general (verb-oriented):

> **Nicht weinen,** *ich schenke dir* dieses Jahr **auch** Blumen zum Geburtstag.

A stupid thing to say - but it expresses that "Blumen zum Geburtstag" will make the difference. "Geschenkt!" should be the answer, which is short for "Du kannst dir deine Blumen **** stecken" (hint: the four-letter solution is not VASE).

This flower/birthday example was badly chosen from the start. Needs the parenthesis *(nicht nur Pralinen)* to clarify.

> you really have to think of someone defending themselves

exactly, phipsgabler

Comment: I can think of no four letter German word that fits in there well. _Sonstwohin_ works, but that's already euphemic.

Comment: A four-letter word in English is not a four-lettered word in German. "Sonstwohin" is what I meant, beside the word that begins with "A-" and has 3 letters in English and 5 in German, but only because of the "-SCH".

Comment: There is no "solution", only a joke with VASE, the real receptacle of flowers. Maybe this basic scene is the source for this saying.

Comment: The point I failed to make is: I don't think you need to refrain from writing _in den Arsch_. (And I didn't get the joke until now, sorry :))

Comment: "damit den Hintern verzieren" or "hinter's Ohr stecken" . After a: "Na, du kannst die doch in eine hübsche Vase stecken" you have many good options, beside the obviuos one.